# How do I remove codes with striptags

Tags: javascript, php, html, host

so, I'm using this host and they injected some code into my index.php... is there anyway to remove them all? I know strip-tags works, but I'm not sure how to use them... it will be nice if anyone could show me some example.. or if anyone have better suggestion than using strip-tags, please let me know.

This is the code that they injected

```html
<div style="text-align: center;"><div style="position:relative; top:0; margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto; z-index:99999">
<iframe id="sc1" width="0" height="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/429476043&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=true&hide_related=true&show_comments=false&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=false&visual=true" style="opacity:0;"></iframe>
 
 <iframe id="sc2" width="0" height="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/488896725&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=true&hide_related=true&show_comments=false&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=false&visual=true" style="opacity:0;"></iframe>
 
 <script src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   (function(){
     var widgetIframe1 = document.getElementById('sc1'),
         widget1       = SC.Widget(widgetIframe1);
 
     widget1.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
       widget1.setVolume(0);
     });
   }());
   
   (function(){
     var widgetIframe2 = document.getElementById('sc2'),
         widget2       = SC.Widget(widgetIframe2);
     widget2.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
        widget2.setVolume(0);
     });
   }());
 </script>
</div></div>
```

EDIT: Just realised that they actually inject the code in every php that I have, not just index.php

Comment: If your host is doing this, switch hosts. There's no excuse for that.

Comment: You should start by contacting your host and finding out why they are doing this. In the meantime you could just do: `document.getElementById('sc1').parentNode.parentNode.remove();`, if need be add a delay to the snippet.

Comment: it's a free host, that's why I can't really complain...But this is just too annoying, maximum volume with annoying music... I just need to use this host for maybe a month of two.. @Script47 I tried adding the code in the end of my index.php, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: hmmm ... how do you know this is done by the hosting company ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I have the same files installed on localhost and the hosting company, localhost didn't have these scripts

Comment: fyi :  although it may not be the case here, you could be  victim of some form of **[code injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Code_Injection)**. It is best to clarify with your hosting company whether this is their policy, and if not, well you got your work cut out for you.